# Fixed effect not siginificant in multi-level model, what else to report besides significance?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, effect-size

I'm studying the effects of a teaching style intervention on student motivation. I use multi-level modeling since students are nested within teachers. The condition main effect is not significant (*p* = .095). This is likely due to the small sample of 8 teachers. I still think the results are promising, since there is a pretty large effect in the desired direction. What else can I report besides significance?

I've studied literature about likelihood ratio and multi-level effect sizes, but I'm having problems figuring out how to calculate them for this case.

> More detailed information:
>
> 331 students nested within 8 teachers (4 in experimental, 4 in control). The fixed effect of condition is 0.24 with standard error of 0.12, t(7.6) = 1.9, p = 0.095. Motivation measured on a 1-5 scale with SD = 0.49. I'm using lme4 in R.